# vue eslint not throwing error on unused methods or computed properties

Tags: vuejs2, eslint

I am using Vue v2 and sublime 3 as text editor. For some reason eslint does not highlight unused computed properties or methods in my components. Other warnings / errors do work.

I followed general recommendations as per official [docs](https://eslint.vuejs.org/user-guide/#editor-integrations)

Here is my eslint file:

```
module.exports = {
  extends: [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:vue/essential",
    "plugin:vue/strongly-recommended",
    "plugin:vue/recommended", // Use this if you are using Vue.js 2.x.
    "prettier",
  ],
  rules: {},
};
```

My dev-dependencies:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "sass": "~1.32.0",
    "sass-loader": "^10.0.0",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "~2.4.5",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.7.0"
  },
```

And lastly, my sublimeLinter settings:

```
// SublimeLinter Settings - User
{
  "linters": {
    "eslint": {
      "selector": "text.html.vue, source.js - meta.attribute-with-value",
      "env": {
        "PATH": "/Users/XXXXXX/.nvm/versions/node/v17.1.0/bin/"
      },
      "args": ["--env=es6"]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I know this is old, but I just came across it looking for something similar. Do you still have the problem? Can you post your .vue file?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [vue/no-unused-properties](https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/no-unused-properties.html#options) in rules.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35216360)